# Custom font is displayed weird

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

From the start I need to say that I know what I'm trying to do is not "the right way to do it", but the client I'm working for desperately wants THIS specific font.

So, I need to use on a client's website the exact font as VOGUE uses. So I took the .eot & .ttf and uploaded them on my server. Then I added the CSS definitions:

```
/*fonts fonts for IE*/
@font-face {
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "VogueDidot Light";
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*fonts for other browsers*/
@font-face {
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "VogueDidot Light";
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And the CSS for my element is:

```
.post h1 {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 58px;
}
```

And, normally, I expected to see everything working like a charm.

But it's not...

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

And that's how it looks on my website :

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link? Do you have maybe any iframes on that page? For me that caused the same issue....

Comment: You'll want to use a good font converter so you're supporting all the major browsers.  Try fontsquirrel.com

Comment: @hjuster unfortunately I am on a local server for now :(

Comment: @Titanium I need that exact same font and I already have it on both .eot and .ttf (exactly as it is on the Vogue site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the browser is trying to display the font bold and repeating the gray pixels (from the thin lines) next to each other. Try using `font-weight: normal` (The `font-weight:bold` is inherited from the h1 element).

Comment: The `font-weight: bold` setting is not inherited; instead, it is a default setting for `h1` in most browsers. But the basic explanation is correct: when the font is declared as `normal` and CSS (browser default style sheet, in this case) requests for `bold`, browsers may use algorithmic bolding.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue :)